# android failed Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

can anyone help me how i fix that

**android: failed
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
Failed to find target with hash string
'1.3.50' in: C:\Users\MB\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**

this from event log

**20:29 Gradle sync started
20:29   Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available. (2 s 996 ms)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one or two build tools versions that you project needs. Check your target and compile versions of your project and then install the build tools for that level. If you have time you can just install it one by one to figure out which one is missing.

E.g If your target is 28, install build tools 28.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.1 and 28.0.0